# Unable to open file using File f = new File(file_pth);

Tags: java, file, netbeans, io, drag

I am trying to open a file by drag and drop onto JTextField but i always get the error.

Heres my code

```
  public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
  String str4=null;
  try {
    JTextArea comp = null;
    if(Switchtab==2)
        comp=textarea1;
     if(Switchtab==3)
        comp=textarea2;
      if(Switchtab==4)
        comp=textarea3;
       if(Switchtab==1)
        comp=textarea4;

  // Ok, get the dropped object and try to figure out what it is
  Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
  DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
  for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Possible flavor: "
        + flavors[i].getMimeType());
    // Check for file lists specifically
    if (flavors[i].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
      // Great! Accept copy drops...
      dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
     // comp.setText("Successful file list drop.\n\n");

      // And add the list of file names to our text area
      java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr
          .getTransferData(flavors[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        //wcomp.append(list.get(j) + "\n");
       str4=list.get(j)+"\n";

      }

     // Replace '\' with '/' 
      file_pth = str4.replaceAll("\\\\","/" );  
     System.out.println(str4.replaceAll("\\\\","/" ));

      //Open the file


        try {



                File f = new File(file_pth);
                FileInputStream fobj = new FileInputStream(f);
                int len = (int) f.length();
                str4 = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    char str5 = (char) fobj.read();
                    str4 = str4 + str5;

                }

                comp.setText(str4);


            setTitle(str4);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught::" + e);
        }

      // If we made it this far, everything worked.
      dtde.dropComplete(true);
      return;
    }
  }
  // Hmm, the user must not have dropped a file list
  System.out.println("Drop failed: " + dtde);
  dtde.rejectDrop();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  dtde.rejectDrop();
}
}
```

I even tried replacing backslash with double backslash and forward slash but still i get this error

```
Possible flavor: application/x-java-file-list; class=java.util.List
C:/kevin_java/file io/DemoIO.java

Caught::java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\kevin_java\file io\DemoIO.java
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

The output doesnt show the replaced string.
It shows the previous string with single backslash.

Comment: Post your error/exception

Comment: Do you actually have a space in your directory name? (`file io`) Does it work for files that *don't* have a space?

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the path? `File f = new File("c:/kevin_java/file io/DemoIO.java");` and are you sure that's the correct path?

Comment: @kamil i have already posted my error

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i do have space in my directory. I get the same error if i do it in a directory with no spaces

Comment: @ElliottFrisch       Yes my code works fine if i hard code the path.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#isFlavorJavaFileListType%28%29) for `isFlavorJavaFileListType`,

> Returns true if the DataFlavor specified represents a list of file objects.

Therefor,

```
FileInputStream fobj = new FileInputStream(list.get(list.length()-1));
```

Comment: The main problem is in the line  File f = new File(file_pth); I am not able to get the valid file_pth .

Comment: @user3712382 Actually, `str4=list.get(j)+"\n";` is the problem. Note that there's no String addition so you only get the last list element (and it has a trailing newline!) with `file_pth = str4.replaceAll("\\\\","/");`

Comment: But i am still not getting a valid filepath even after using trim()

Comment: Are you still getting the same Exception?

Comment: str4 = (String) list.get(list.size() - 1); I got the exception    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: @Kevin Edited. Call `toString()`, don't cast to a String.

Comment: Even after using toString() i got same exception     Caught::java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\kevin_java\file io\DemoIO.java
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: @Kevin Edited to fix my answer. And your call to `isFlavorJavaFileListType` means your List is already Files.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got my answer.
Simple solution

```
java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr
          .getTransferData(flavors[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

       str4=list.get(j).toString();

      }

 File f = new File(str4);
                FileInputStream fobj = new FileInputStream(f);
...
...
..
```